# Как элементы задать alpha канал корректно. Проблема с разметкой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите пожалуйста исправить дефект верстки.

**CSS:**

```
div.date { 
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 30px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 60px; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity:0.3
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class"date">7 мая</div>
```

**Ожидание:**

Прозрачный div элемент и с белой непрозрачной надписью по центру.

**Реальность:**

Белая надпись тоже прозрачна, а текст не посередине.

[image: Бага в верстке]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div.date { 
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;/* center text */
    color:#ffffff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3); /* меняем opacity на background - rgba */
    border-radius: 60px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="date">text date</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
div.date { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 30px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 60px;
}
```